# Deleting a character in an element of a 2D list in Python

Tags: python, list, 2d

I'm working with two dimensional lists in python

I have a list of strings (`m= [[0]*5 for i in range(5)]`)

After splitting another string and storing it in `m` I get the elements of `m` as follows:

```
m[0] = "< one"

m[1] = "two" 

m[2] = "three" 

m[3] = "four"

m[4] = "five >"
```

How can I delete the `<` character from element 0 and the `>` character from the element 4?

I'm trying to parse a string s. I'm parsing it so I can later store the values into a database. That's why I need the < to be eliminated.

ACTUAL CODE:

```
    s ="< one > < two > < three > < four : 1 > < five : 2 > < six : 3 > < seven : 4 > < eight : 5 > < nine : 6 >"
    m= [[0]*5 for i in range(5)]
    m=s.split("> <")
    print "The original list"
    index=0
    for index in m:
        print index
```

OUTPUT:

The original list

< one

two

three

four : 1

five : 2

six : 3

seven : 4

eight : 5

nine : 6 >

Comment: how is that a list of string?  It looks like a list of lists of integers ...

Comment: i've edited my question can you look at it again and tell me if i should use something else instead

Comment: @NidhiPaul You're just overwriting `m` with the result of the split - so you're not doing anything with a list of lists... On a side note, it looks like you just want to extract your data in a different way to avoid needing to do this - I've included an answer which I believe is what you're really after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about splitting the string properly to start with?

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

s ="< one > < two > < three > < four : 1 > < five : 2 > < six : 3 > < seven : 4 > < eight : 5 > < nine : 6 >"
res = re.findall('< (.*?) >', s)
pprint(res)
```

Gives you:

```
['one',
 'two',
 'three',
 'four : 1',
 'five : 2',
 'six : 3',
 'seven : 4',
 'eight : 5',
 'nine : 6']
```

Comment: wow that's awesome I've been breaking my head over this for a while! could you explain the regular expression you used, what does (.*?) imply

Comment: @NidhiPaul It means take everything until what matches next... (so in this case, everything up to a space followed by a `>` So find everything after a `< ` and take everything until ` >`

Comment: ok so that's just one string, what i'm trying to implement is a function that parses a string like the one i've posted here and strings in two additional formats
once i've parsed the string i have to store the data into a MySQL database
is this the best way to parse the string so i can extract the data to put it into the database or would you suggest something else?

Comment: @NidhiPaul hard to say without more information - and is perhaps best as a separate question :)

Comment: cool =) how could i further extract the numbers 1 2,3,4,5,6 from res after using the findall function?

Answer (score 1):

And there he released the code... My answer then becomes:

```
s ="< one > < two > < three > < four : 1 > < five : 2 > < six : 3 > < seven : 4 > < eight : 5 > < nine : 6 >" 
m=s.split("> <") 

m[0].replace("<", "")
m[-1].replace(">", "")

print m
>>> [' one ', ' two ', ' three ', ' four : 1 ', ' five : 2 ', ' six : 3 ', ' seven : 4 ', ' eight : 5 ', ' nine : 6 ']
```

Comment: Or just unconditionally slice it, n[1:-1] - or with conditionals, you could do this monstrosity... `n[n[0]=='<':-(n[-1]=='>') or None]`

Comment: i've edited my question could you look at it again, i wasn't clear before? :)

Comment: @NidhiPaul - It's updated, i think it might just work. Still hard to understand what your tryin' to achive. So i guessed.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'

Answer (score 0):

Your output doesn't look right- are you sure you're storing your items in a list? I suggest doing some research on lists, and once you get that figured out you can simply use the remove() method:

```
m = ["<", "a", "b", "c", "d", ">"]

m.remove("<")
m.remove(">")

print m 

>>>['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

EDIT: just saw your edit and it doesn't make much sense- you can't have two different values occupying the same list index space (m[2] in your case)

Comment: whoops, that was a typo. would you have another look at it?

Comment: remove doesn't work because the element stored is "< one" hence when it searches for "<" it's not a match with m[0] as m[0] is "< one"

Comment: i need something that will remove the "<" from within m[0] so that m[0] ="one" and not "< one"

Comment: @NidhiPaul I understand what you're trying to do. Try posting all of your code so we can get a better sense of the context.

Comment: s ="< one > < two > < three > < four : 1 > < five : 2 > < six : 3 > < seven : 4 > < eight : 5 > < nine : 6 >"
m= [[0]*5 for i in range(5)]
m=s.split("> <")
print "The original list"
index=0
for index in m:
    print index
Here's the

Comment: Nidhi, buddy... In the future don't post large blocks of code in comments. Edit your original question and practice formatting it correctly.

Comment: Cool will do, this is my first question here I've edited the question now cause I figured that would be a problem :)

Comment: Is there something I can do to work with this code or do I need to use a completely different approach?